# Filling a global static array at startup

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14

How can I fill a static array at startup, other than specifying an exhaustive list of its elements in the source (bloating the source and the binary)?

This is the best I could come up with to fill `array` with values from 0 to 99 dynamically:

```
int array[100];

struct FillArray {
    FillArray() {
        std::iota(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 0);
    }
};

FillArray dummy;
```

Is there a more idiomatic pattern for this out there?

The definition of the array can't change: it must look like a static array to calling code (e.g., don't suggest using `std::array`).

---

<sup>Note that I am not looking to solve the static initialization order problem. That is, you may assume that other than the initialization, the array is not accessed again until after `main()` begins.</sup>

Comment: Can array be moved inside of a class?

Comment: In this case no, since it has to be accessed simply as `array` by both C-like C++ code and C code. If I could though, is there an elegant solution? @Jarod42

Comment: You might still do `c_function(my_class.array)`. or `c_function(std_array.data(), std_array.size())`

Comment: @Jarod42 - yes, but that's for calling a C function with this data. In this case, C functions have to use the array direction from C code (i.e., they share the array declaration via header).

Comment: `__attribute__ ((constructor ()))` is also an option, and if you need to prioritize multiple constructor/destructor functions, you can provide sequential numbers (beginning at `101`, e.g. `__attribute__ ((constructor (101)))`) Constructors are then run in the order of the numbers and desctructors are called in then the reverse order.

Comment: Thanks David - I think this is a non-portable attribute, right? I was hoping for a pure C++ solution. I added to a note to clarify that I don't need to worry about static init order in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is some version of a [Schwarz Counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) (better known as a Nifty Counter).

A Nifty Counter is used to initialise a non-local static object before the first use in your program, and destroy it after the last use.

An example of a Nifty Counter in the std lib, is std::cout.

Here is an example for your use case:

```
// GlobalArray.hpp

#pragma once

#include <array>

struct GlobalArray // This the the struct containing the 'static' object we want 
{
    GlobalArray();
    ~GlobalArray();
    std::array<int, 100> array;

};
extern GlobalArray& global_array; // This is the variable containing the reference to the constructed 'static' object. 

static struct GlobalArrayInit
{
    GlobalArrayInit();
    ~GlobalArrayInit();
} global_array_init;
```

And now...

```
// GlobalArray.cpp

#include "GlobalArray.hpp"

static int nifty_counter; // zero initialised at load time
static typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof (GlobalArray), alignof (GlobalArray)>::type
  global_array_buf; // memory for the global_array object
GlobalArray& global_array = reinterpret_cast<GlobalArray&> (global_array_buffer);

GlobalArray::GlobalArray ()
{
  // initialize things
}
GlobalArray::~GlobalArray ()
{
  // clean-up
} 

GlobalArrayInit::GlobalArrayInit ()
{
  if (nifty_counter++ == 0) new (&global_array) GlobalArray (); // placement new
}
GlobalArrayInit::~GlobalArrayInit ()
{
  if (--nifty_counter == 0) (&global_array)->~GlobalArray ();
}
```

Note that you HAVE to include the header before using the the 'global_array' object, to insure it has been constructed correctly.

If you wish to read further into how this is working, and where I got the idea for the source code, please read this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter

Comment: Interesting, but I think you are trying to solve an entirely different (more difficult) problem, which seems to be: construction of an object only if a header that uses it is included in a particular program and/or the static init ordering problem? It is way more boilerplate than what I showed, and changes the array declaration by moving it inside a class.